# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_79_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (99, 4457, 4)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

This is a binary classifcation CNN model of RNA seq using one hot encoding. The dataset is already one hot encoded and my X shape is
(99, 4457, 4)

I have tried to increase the dimensions using:

```
arr4d = np.expand_dims(X, 0)
```

Which gave me shape of:
(1, 99, 4457, 4)

But then I received another error:

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_64 to have shape (4,) but got array with shape (1,)

I have tried several other ways too but I am just not doing this correctly. Any help is much appreciated.

```
X = np.reshape(X2, (X2.shape[0],maximum,4))


# In[62]:


def build_cnn():

    model = Sequential()

    # Multiple convolution operations to detect features in the images
    model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=3,activation='relu',input_shape=(99,4457,4)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=3,activation='relu')) # no need to specify shape as there is a layer before
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=5,strides=2,padding='same',activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.4)) # reduce overfitting

    model.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=3,activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=3,activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=5,strides=2,padding='same',activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.4)) # reduce overfitting

    # Flattening and classification by standard ANN
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model


# In[63]:


model = build_cnn()
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=64, epochs=16)
```

Comment: Why is the title of your question an error that you already solved? Let's concentrate in the issue about the targets, what is the shape of y?

Answer (score 0):

Which gave me shape of: (1, 99, 4457, 4) it is definitely wrong shape. Images usualy have  (batch_size, channels, height, width).
 After convolution with kernel_size=3 what are 3x3 maps the shape will be (1,32, 4457-2, 4-2) and can not be processed with next conv2d

Comment: Thank you but this is not an image dataset. This is an RNA seq dataset,

Comment: what content dies it have, can you explain or give me a link? I ll tell the right shape then. Hm i guess you should have 1d Convo here